# Can we merge the cryptography and crypto tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

There is [crypto](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto) and [cryptography](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography). I suggest [cryptography](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) should be the preferred tag and that [crypto](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto) should be a synonym. Though currently [crypto](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crypto) has more questions.

Answer (score 4):

This seems fairly uncontroversial, so I've gone ahead and merged and synonmised them.

If anyone can think of reasons why this shouldn't have been done, I'm all ears.